# java.lang.NullPointerException at HttpClient.execute

Tags: java, android, apache, junit, httpclient

I've been struggling with this error while running a Unit Test using Junit. (More an Integration test, because the idea is to check if the library is returning the response). But I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alliancetech.util.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:84)
    at com.alliancetech.atdroidnetworklib.ITAssociationsAPI.testAssociationsByEventID(ITAssociationsAPI.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

RestClient.execute is calling HttpClient's execute method, however the response object is always a null.

I'm new to Junit and I have never done an Integration test using it. I looked if it was possible and it says it is, but right now I'm not sure.

Here is my test code:

```
public class ITAssociationsAPI extends ITLeadsRestTest {

    @Before
    public void setup(){}

    @Test
    public void testAssociationsByEventID(){
        String urlGetAssociationsById = API_URL + "rest of the url";
        RestClient rcAssociationsByEventID = new RestClient(urlGetAssociationsById);

        // Checks if the http code was 200.
        int code = rcAssociationsByEventID.execute();
        assertEquals(200, code);

        // Checks if the response is not null
        JSONObject content = rcAssociationsByEventID.getJSONResponse();
        assertNotNull(content);

        // Checks if the content is a JSON body
        boolean valid = isContentJSON(content);
        assertEquals(true, valid);
    }

}

public abstract class ITLeadsRestTest extends TestCase{

    protected final String API_URL = "*******";

    protected boolean isContentJSON(JSONObject content){
        boolean valid = false;

        JSONObject validator = content;

        return valid;
    }

}
```

Any light on this would be greatly appreciated.

***Edit***

Here is the RestClient code:

```
public class RestClient {

private static final String TAG = "RestClient";
private String url;
private HttpResponse response;
private JSONObject body = null;
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;

protected RestClient(){}

public static class RestClientException extends RuntimeException
{
    public RestClientException( Exception exc )
    {
        super(exc);
    }
}

public RestClient(String url)
{
    this.url = url;
    params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

}

public void addQueryParam( String name, String value )
{
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
}

public void setBody( JSONObject jsonObj )
{
    this.body = jsonObj;
}

public int execute()
{

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String uri = null;
    try {
        uri = (params.isEmpty())? url : url + getParams();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        uri = url;
    }

    try {
        response = client.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
        StatusLine status =response.getStatusLine();
        int result = status.getStatusCode();
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RestClientException(e);
    }
}

public JSONObject getJSONResponse()
{
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        return (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(out.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RestClientException(e);
    }
}

public JSONArray getJSONResponseArray()
{
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        return (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(out.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RestClientException(e);
    }
}

private final String getParams()
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuffer combinedParams = new StringBuffer();
    if (!params.isEmpty()) {
        combinedParams.append("?");
        for (NameValuePair p : params) {
           combinedParams.append((combinedParams.length() > 1 ? "&" : "")
                    + p.getName() + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
    }
    return combinedParams.toString();
}

public final int executePost(File inputFile) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String uri = null;
    try {
        uri = (params.isEmpty())? url : url + getParams();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        uri = url;
    }

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//            FileEntity entity = new FileEntity( inputFile, "application/json" );
            InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity( new FileInputStream(inputFile), inputFile.length());
            post.setEntity( entity );
            response = client.execute( post );
            StatusLine status =response.getStatusLine();
            int result = status.getStatusCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "POST RESULT: " + result + "(" + status.getReasonPhrase() + ")");
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RestClientException(e);
        }
    }

public final int executePost() {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String uri = null;
    try {
        uri = (params.isEmpty())? url : url + getParams();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        uri = url;
    }

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity( body.toJSONString(), "UTF-8" );
        post.setEntity( entity );
        response = client.execute( post );
        StatusLine status =response.getStatusLine();
        int result = status.getStatusCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "POST RESULT: " + result + "(" + status.getReasonPhrase() + ")");
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RestClientException(e);
    }
}

public final InputStream contentStream() {
    try {
        return response.getEntity().getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RestClientException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You say that you're checking if the response is not null, but your code says to me that you're continuing with `assertEquals()` even if the response IS null. I wonder why you're getting NPE...

Comment: Can you also provide the RestClient class code?

Comment: Vin I posted the code for the RestClient.

Comment: Which line is `RestClient.java:84` ?

Comment: In the method execute the line is this one: response = client.execute(new HttpGet(uri));